# Streaming Large Video using Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, video-streaming

I'm facing an issue when streaming large video files using Spring MVC. My source code is below. So, it can play a video file which is less than 10 MB, but when I play a video which is 72 MB then the server throws the following Exception: **"ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error"**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/clip/{name}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public void loadVideoFile(@PathVariable String name,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
    FileInputStream in = null;
    ServletOutputStream out = null;
    try {
        if (bundle == null)
            bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("course");

        if (!bundle.containsKey("course.clip.Page" + name))
            return;

        String filePath = bundle.getString("course.clip.Page" + name);

        int fileSize = (int) new File(filePath).length();
        response.setContentLength(fileSize);
        response.setContentType("video/mp4");
        in = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        out = response.getOutputStream();
        int value = IOUtils.copy(in, out);


        System.out.println("File Size :: " + fileSize);
        System.out.println("Copied Bytes :: " + value);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(in);
        IOUtils.closeQuietly(out);
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    } catch (java.io.FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
    }finally{

    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help to solve this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Indrek, I realize this is an older post, but any updates regarding how this may have been resolved (for historical purposes) would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd think you'd need to change this to support Range requests and return Partial Content.   Check out http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/02/fileservlet-supporting-resume-and.html

Comment: `ClientAbortException` makes me suspect the problem isn't caused server side. I don't see an immediate problem with large files being sent this way.